The cloth is falling apart
I added a cloth texture for the machine gun belt, but its placement just fell apart. How do I fix this? I'm a beginner.


you have several problems here: 1) never use a complicated mesh to do cloth simulation. Just use one simple mesh line with one extrusion (so you have a simple face line), hook the 4 end points/vertices to empties, use that 4 vertices as pin group for that cloth. 2) make sure your "real" geometry (the belt) is just one connected mesh object and object (yours isn't). Then you can use a surface deform modifier to your real belt with the cloth modifier as target. Don't forget to check "self collision" to your cloth. good luck.

Hey, how can I link it? I used merge, but the inner elements remained unattached When enabling self-collision, the internal blocks got stuck randomly, and some were pushed out. For some reason, it doesn't seem to be considered a single object.

You have overlapping vertices, select all and press M to merge by distance, merge all the meshes into one mesh, otherwise they will fall apart, create a vertex group where the object is supposed to be attached and select it as Pin Group in the Cloth panel, give a Collision simulation to the gun so that it acts like an obstacle, parent the belt to the gun.

Thank you, to some extent that helped, but the inner blocks are still not  linked. When collision is self-enabled, half of them randomly get stuck inside, while the other half gets pushed out.

yes they should not be separated mesh, you need to either extrude these blocks from the existing belt, or separate them as separate object and parent to the vertices of the belt (select the block, shift select the belt, switch to Edit mode, select 3 vertices and Ctrl P to parent to the vertices

Oh, can I somehow use editing mode during animation playback? It would be more convenient for me to highlight the inner blocks when they fall out

@Saturn1401 you can use shape keys, though I think they will work as desired after you bake your cloth simulation to keyframes

I tried, but I think I'll just extrude the blocks
